# Вопросы по Alarm

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте,

Предположим у меня есть один `editText`, в который я что-то ввел. И есть `AlarmManager`. Я создал какое-то событие и закрыл приложение. Настало событие и появилось уведомление. Так вот интересуют два вопроса:

1) По нажатию на уведомление я перехожу на заданную `Activity` в приложение. Как реализовать, чтобы я мог по нажатию на уведомление открыть `Activity` и увидеть, что я
вводил в editText?

2) Возможно ли создавать несколько `Alarm'`ов? Например, создал на 15 и 17 часов. Или только по очереди ? Вначале на 15, как пройдет, можно будет на 17?

```
Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();
calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timePicker.getCurrentHour());
calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timePicker.getCurrentMinute());
calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Храните состояние edittext в SharedPreferences или БД и восстанавливайте при запуске. На какой активити перейти реализуется через Notifications.

2) Можно. Придет первое - потом второе, насколько я помню. 
[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273342/how-can-i-setup-multiple-alarms-in-android)

Comment: 2)по-моему там надо задавать различные id, чтобы выпало 2 оповещения (если я вообще правильно понял о чем вопрос)